# Detect serial ports installed on Android device

Tags: android, linux, serial-port

I have various devices with serial ports and I connect a printer to them. The problem is that for configure I have to show to the user all the tty files of the `/dev` directory.

I've found that the file `/proc/tty/drivers` contains the prefix of the serial devices:

> ```
>  serial    /dev/ttyS    4 64-95 serial
> ```

I want to know only the real serial ports installed on the device. This approximation tells me that
my device serial ports are :

> ```
> /dev/ttyS0
> /dev/ttyS1
> /dev/ttyS2
> /dev/ttyS3
> ```

But only ttyS0 and ttyS1 exists on my device. How can I detect that?

Note: On a PC with Linux I can do `/dmesg | grep tty` and returns me the serial ports installed on the PC. Unfortunately on my Android devices this command does not return anything.

Note 2 : Using `/proc/tty/drivers` I can't discriminate between serial ports and usb ports because all of them are tagged as serial.